# Using inRange() in OpenCV to detect colors in a range

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, hough-transform

I'm writing a C++ program with OpenCV for lunar crater detection which seems to detect only a small fraction of craters accurately. My strategy for this approach was to first convert the image to HSV, then use `inRange()` to catch the colors in a range of values to produce a threshold, then Gaussian blur it and use `HoughCircles()` to detect the circles.

One thing that I am not fully understanding is that when I give `inRange()` a low and high threshold around a color, it simply does not return anything. Just a black image. It only works when I set the low threshold to `Scalar(0,0,0)` however I believe this makes it somewhat inaccurate. Is there something I am not understanding about this? My test image is below.

Lunar Surface [image]

This is the code that I used to test this image:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // using namespace cv;

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    Mat src=imread(argv[1]);

    if (!src.data) {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\topening image" <<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // converts the image to hsv so that circle detection is more accurate
    Mat hsv_image;
    cvtColor(src, hsv_image, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    // high contrast black and white
    Mat imgThreshold;
    inRange(hsv_image,
        Scalar(0, 0, 0),
        Scalar(48, 207, 74),
        imgThreshold);

    // Applies a gaussian blur to the image
    GaussianBlur( imgThreshold, imgThreshold, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
    // fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, 10, 10, 7, 21);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    // applies a hough transform to the image
    HoughCircles(imgThreshold, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        2, // accumulator resolution (size of image / 2)
        100, //minimum dist between two circles
        400, // Canny high threshold
        10, // minimum number of votes
        10, 65); // min and max radius

    cout << circles.size() << endl;
    cout << "end of test" << endl;

    vector<Vec3f>::
          const_iterator itc = circles.begin();
    // Draws the circles on the source image
    while (itc!=circles.end()) {

        circle(src, // src_gray2
            Point((*itc)[0], (*itc)[1]), // circle center
            (*itc)[2],       // circle radius
            Scalar(0,0,255), // color
            5);              // thickness

        ++itc;
    }
    namedWindow("Threshold",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    resize(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, Size(src.cols/2,src.rows/2) ); // resizes it so it fits on our screen
    imshow("Threshold",imgThreshold); // displays the source iamge

    namedWindow("HSV Color Space",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    resize(hsv_image, hsv_image, Size(src.cols/2,src.rows/2) ); // resizes it so it fits on our screen
    imshow("HSV Color Space",hsv_image); // displays the source iamge

    namedWindow("Source Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    resize(src, src, Size(src.cols/2,src.rows/2) ); // resizes it so it fits on our screen
    imshow("Source Image",src); // displays the source iamge

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you tried to call [`inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) with lower bound of `(28,50,100)` and upper bound of `(7, 216, 213)`? The documentation is quite clear about what the function does. In this case for channel 0, you're calculating the result of `28 <= x <= 7`, which will never be true. Since all the results for individual channels and ANDed together, the overall result can thus also never be true. Read the docs!

Comment: @DanMašek No that is not correct, I did not try to call that. That was simply an unlabeled comment for several _upper bounds_ which I tested against a lower bound of (0,0,0). Yes I thoroughly reviewed the docs, which was the first thing I did.

Comment: So, what's the part that doesn't work? I mean there's only one call to that function, and according to what you wrote " It only works when I set the low threshold to `Scalar(0,0,0)`". Also, if the comments are not relevant, then don't show them in the question (it takes few seconds to delete irrelevant junk).

Comment: @DanMašek as I mentioned in the question "when I give inRange() a low and high threshold around a color, it simply does not return anything. Just a black image" so to elaborate a little more on that I'll give an example. Let's say I have an RGB color of (66,53,10) which I picked from the image and convert it to hsv (23,216,66) when I use inRange on two bounds (let's say (13,206,56) to (33,226,76) surrounding that color, it simply returns a black image as if it didn't find the color whatsoever. Am I doing this correctly? It seems to not work even when I open up the bounds more.

Comment: And it works with limited success when the lower bound is Scalar(0,0,0) because it highlights too much of the image - it's not selective enough. Though it does work, that contradicts the docs and several examples I found online so I'm having trouble figuring out _why_ this is

Comment: @DanMašek Most people read the docs before asking a question, childish to assume the OP didn't.

Comment: @shakked :D Spend some more time on Stack Overflow, and let me know if you still hold that opinion. IMHO the `opencv` tag on its own is a sufficient proof of the contrary.

Comment: @DanMašek Haha, maybe after another 4 years I'll understand

Comment: @AlexanderVallorosi For example, I can't find a single pixel with the exact color you specified. However `inRange` with the range you mentioned will find 147 pixels (in OpenCV 3.x, it's one less with OpenCV 2.x, presumably due to some changes in the code that converts to HSV) both in C++ as well as in Python. I guess you're setting the ranges too tight. Perhaps try a reverse approach to determine better ranges -- manually create a mask that highlights all the pixels you want to detect. Based on that, extract all the pixel values, and determine what range(s) you need to have to match them all.

Comment: @DanMašek One thing I should mention as well is that I pick the color from the HSV image not from the source, since the threshold is applied to the HSV image. Is that the correct way to look at it? That's a great idea I didn't think of it, thank you for that, I can give it a shot!

Comment: @AlexanderVallorosi Can you share the best result you have after the `inrange` step? I did some tests using 2  `inRange `s (`(0,0,0) ` to  `(48,207,74)` and `(150,0,0)` to `(180,207,114)`) and combined the 2 resulting thresholds. That gave pretty good results that can be further improved with morphological operations.

Comment: Hello @ElouarnLaine thank you for your comment. I suppose the result is not bad. Why do the values of Saturation & Value have to start at 0 on the low end? Is it just because of the way the photo is? That is my primary misunderstanding here. If you could point me in the right direction with morphological operations I would appreciate that. Here are the results of my tests with those values:

[Threshold (0,0,0) to (48,207,74)](http://imgur.com/x2ag8cP)
[Result](http://imgur.com/bqqQA11)

[Threshold (150,0,0) to (180,207,114)](http://imgur.com/HZMhonh)
[Result](http://imgur.com/PX9WeWx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src;
    src = imread("craters1.jpg", 1);
    cvtColor(src, hsv_image, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat imgThreshold1, imgThreshold2, imgThreshold;
    inRange(hsv_image,
        Scalar(0, 0, 0),
        Scalar(48, 207, 74),
        imgThreshold1);

    inRange(hsv_image,
        Scalar(140, 0, 0),
        Scalar(180, 207, 114),
        imgThreshold2);

    imgThreshold = max(imgThreshold1, imgThreshold2); // combining the two thresholds

    Mat element_erode = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5));
    Mat element_dilate = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(10, 10));
    /// Apply the erosion and dilation operations
    erode(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, element_erode);
    dilate(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, element_dilate);

    GaussianBlur(imgThreshold, imgThreshold, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    /// Find contours
    findContours(imgThreshold, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(src, contours, i, Scalar(0,0,255), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", imgThreshold);
    imshow("Final result", src);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The main difference with your code is that I don't use `HoughCircles`. I'm not sure it will give good results as craters don't have a perfect circular shape. Instead, I used `findContours` to circle the craters. Here is the result I have:
[image: crater detection result]
Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh wow this is a really great solution. I was somewhat aware of the limitations of HoughCircles to this application, but I didn't know about your findContours solution! So thank you for that! Also, I didn't know that it was possible to combine two thresholds in that way. Thank you for the help this is great.