# Python 3.7 OpenCV empty masks even with correct color range

Tags: python, opencv, mask, color-detection

I have an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy31P.png) that has been converted to HSV format. My goal is to isolate the green and black regions of the image, such that I can compare the area of the green regions and the area of the black regions. I can easily 'isolate' the black region by using OpenCV's inRange function to create a mask that detects black using the lower bound [0,0,0] and upper bound [1,0,0], which gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e2F8.png). Great.

However, when I try to isolate the green region, I face an issue where the mask is just completely black. I have tried using the color ranges found by utilising this [color picker](https://alloyui.com/examples/color-picker/hsv.html), this OpenCV [color picker script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) and Krita's color picker tool, all of which gave me differing ranges. For reference, I'll attach the ranges I have tried. From my understanding of the inRange function, the function spits out whatever output is within the lower and upper bounds that are present in the img file given, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Some references I used include this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966), the [OpenCV documentation page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) and this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981903/using-inrange-in-opencv-to-detect-colors-in-a-range).

Here is my code, which includes the color ranges I have used.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv.imread('contrast.png')
# Convert to HSV format
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# Save file
cv.imwrite('hsv.png', hsv)
# cv.imshow('hsv', hsv)

# Using values from Color Picker from AlloyUI 
lower = np.array([100,210,210])
upper = np.array([145,255,255])
# Using OpenCV color picker script values
# lower = np.array([32,0,0])
# upper = np.array([89, 255, 255])
# Using Krita's color picker tool
# lower = np.array([36,25,25])
# upper = np.array([70,255,255])

# Create mask using lower and upper bounds
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

cv.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv.imshow('mask', mask)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second and third limits? If I run the code using these limits, I get proper masks for the green parts. The hue value of "green" might be set to `[80 ... 160]`. In OpenCV, the hue is scaled to `[0 ... 180]` to fit into an `uint8`. So, lower and upper limits of something like `[40, 0, 0]` and `[80, 255, 255]` should work properly. The second and third limits provided have that range (more or less), thus they're working, too - at least for me.

Comment: Could you show me your results? Using these values all I see is a black screen as the mask.

Comment: Are you referring to the OpenCV window? I also just see a fully gray window, but that's because the window closes instantly at the end of the script. You can circumvent that by adding `cv.waitKey(0)` at the end of your script. Nevertheless, I get a proper `mask.png` for the second and third limits.

Comment: Somehow, I managed to get it to work using Matplotlib.pyplot's plt.imshow() function instead of the OpenCV's cv.imshow() function. I'm not exactly sure why this is the case, but it works now. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: OpenCV's imshow expects uint8 to be scaled in the range 0..255 (and floats to be 0 .. 1). if you give it just 0 and 1 values, that will appear black. matplotlib does automatic scaling.